# ssh-copy-id stuck with CentoOS 7 on docker

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a script that uses ssh-copy-id.

When I try to use a CentOS 7 docker container, the command just stays there, doesn't do anything, doesn't time out, etc.. there is no output besides listing the key it will send.

I have used it on physical CentOS 7 servers before without any problems.

The private key is chmod'ed to 600 and public to 666. I can ssh normally to the container with the key.

since there is no output, I don't know how I can troubleshoot this. Where can I start?

---

Edit, I have run a trace of the script, here is the output (there are IP / keys in it, but it's a local test, so it's irrelevant)

here is the output: https://pastebin.com/M1e4J142

the last few lines are:

```
GET_ID='cat "/Users/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa-172.17.0.2.pub"'
eval cat '"/Users/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa-172.17.0.2.pub"'
cat /Users/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa-172.17.0.2.pub
'[' -z 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDalqOiECQpNo/GQBBnmsU81DdPq9SQfoCZOBgmJ/TPBLHfnlx+5KwXex5PwKC6719xSiwkwlffhoAyMlIOwVlnI6YduCMBlbSvOKwevvGM4+AOkaTIUnTLtUvPFcOW5ckI7f7RLtXVS+InlD7x3Y1SkvI4Q8W4x2foYOC+CAHqcTCESfLzD9PJxBYAgDk1iicmfPi7X0kZtmJsyo+YGXJhn3bpbwxL0UTAx8Ny5eYCyWGSURqJ6k9G8zekRRQDzvRkGqN7wV5bZQSxs6swvAW5sZAoBRYmUxdMdWXoBFrfBkRL8sS/UqKY61ytAYrciKIeN6txg/iSYg9mvm9yauZ thomas@Thomas-MBP-2017' ']'
ssh -v -o PreferredAuthentications=, -o ControlPath=none 172.17.0.2
sed -ne 's/.*remote software version //p'
```

Comment: so container has SSHd running? Also you can try to re-run command prefixed with `strace -f ` - it can give you clue where it is stuck.

Comment: Can you provide command whit which you run container? Have you bounded ports? I asume `-p 22:22` cause you use ssh.

Comment: ssh-copy-id command doesn't need ssh daemon running. In fact, you don't need sshd service at all to copy key. @Thomas is you container authorized to talk with the host you want to copy your pub key?

Comment: I added the trace; yes, I have full access to the container; it's running locally and I can ssh to it without problem